# How can I temporally pause a Flutter Stream Builder listening to stream changes during a process?

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

how can i prevent the stream builder from listening to the stream changes during a specific process and start listening to the stream changes again after the process is finished.

i was trying to prevent the stream builder from listening to the userchanges() during just a specific process.